# Spark job as a web service?

Tags: apache-spark, web-services, azure-databricks

A peer of mine has created code that opens a restful api web service within an interactive spark job.  The intent of our company is to use his code as a means of extracting data from various datasources.  He can get it to work on his machine with a local instance of spark.  He insists that this is a good idea and it is my job as DevOps to implement it with Azure Databricks.

As I understand it interactive jobs are for one-time analytics inquiries and for the development of non-interactive jobs to be run solely as ETL/ELT work between data sources.  There is of course the added problem of determining the endpoint for the service binding within the spark cluster.

But I'm new to spark and I have scarcely delved into the mountain of documentation that exists for all the implementations of spark.  Is what he's trying to do a good idea?  Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

The web-service would need to act as a Spark Driver. Just like you'd run `spark-shell`, run some commands ,  and  then use `collect()` methods to bring all data to be shown in the local environment, that all runs in a singular JVM environment. It would submit executors to a remote Spark cluster, then bring the data back over the network. Apache Livy is one existing implementation for a REST Spark submission server.

It can be done, but depending on the process, it would be very asynchronous, and it is not suggested for large datasets, which Spark is meant for. Depending on the data that you need (e.g. highly using SparkSQL), it'd be better to query a database directly.